# Lubuntu 14.04.1 - load installer components from cd fails, although integrity is ok - why?

Tags: usb, system-installation, lubuntu, uefi, secure-boot

I am trying to install lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-amd64 on a USB Stick - and oh my, is that some trouble.

**My Setup:**

Win7 UEFI System with enabled Secure Boot

**My Target:**

64GB USB 3.0 Stick in USB3 Port, GPT, has ESI Partition, Fat32 Partition, 8302 Ext4 home, Swap, 8304 Ext4 root

**My Sources:**

- lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso based Install-CD (somehow not
  bootable)
- lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso based Install-SDCard
  (done with dd copy of the iso, bootable)
- my target has the lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso on his Fat32 partition and I can
  boot from it

**My Problem:**

I can boot the SDCard, Check the Disk, everything is OK, but "Load installer components from CD" fails.

I've checked the ISO and it's contents with md5, all is fine. I can even use the ISO in a UEFI based VM and the problem is not there. However, my VM won't accept my multiparitioned USB-Stick.

Because the GUI-Based installer tries to mess with my partitions, I am using the alternate-ISO. I don't want to format my partitions, I just want a system copied to them.

**My Goal:**

An USB Stick that is bootable on a UEFI System with active secure boot, that boots to Win7 by default and a Lubuntu 14.04.1 from the Stick by choice.

Due to a specific partitioning that is aligned and adjusted to my USB Stick I do not want to change any parition sizes and which to not format them.

---

Is there any way to achieve this? Because I am currently at the end of my rope here :(

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I guess, although it was not the exact same situation, I had a simillar problem to this: https://askubuntu.com/q/439661/319747

And suprisingly the same solution - just by chance I've left my boot-cd in the drive and started from the SDCard - and suddenly it went installing.

Still this is very strange and anybody who would rely on having just an USBStick or SDCard would go crazy - because the CheckDiskIntegrity works, even without a CD present, but loading the installer components won't!

Although my answer is a solution, I will accept who ever explains how this can be fixed without using a Boot-CD.